# What is the Schmidt basis equivalent for a mixed state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

A pure state can be locally transformed unitarily to its Schmidt basis given by

$$|\psi\rangle_{AB} = \sum_i \alpha_i |i\rangle_A \otimes |i\rangle_B$$

where $A$ and $B$ are both diagonalized, and can be seen to have the same spectrum.

For a mixed state $\rho_{AB}$, A and B do not have the same spectrum, but its subsystems $\rho_{A(B)} = \mathrm{Tr}_{B(A)} \rho_{AB}$ should both be diagonalizable at the same time, what is such a basis?

Comment: Well, just diagonalize the two reduced density matrices.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Ok. Is there a particular name associated with it?

Comment: Eigenbasis of $\rho_A$ and eigenbasis of $\rho_B$?  I think you are looking for something which is not there!